Flowbite date-range-picker: How to get selected dates? (angular)
I have implemented the Flowbite date-range-picker in my UI, but I am unable to fetch the chosen dates from the input fields.
I have tried:

The change event: (change)="onStartDateChange($event)"
Adding event listener on element using ViewChild/elementRef

Interestingly, the event listener using ViewChild/elementRef does work if the event is 'click' (but then it has wrong behavior), but does not work when the event is 'change'
TS:
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from 

'@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'date-range-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-range-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-range-picker.component.scss'],
})
export class DateRangePickerComponent {
  startDate: Date | null = null;
  endDate: Date | null = null;

  @Output() dateRangeSelected = new EventEmitter<{ startDate: Date; endDate: Date; }>();

  @ViewChild('datepickerRangeStart', { static: false }) startDateInput!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('datepickerRangeEnd', { static: false }) endDateInput!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  onStartDateChange(event: any): void {
    console.log('--- Start date change event:', event);
    this.startDate = event.target.value ? new Date(event.target.value) : null;
    this.emitDateRangeIfComplete();
  }

  onEndDateChange(event: any): void {
    console.log('--- End date change event:', event);
    this.endDate = event.target.value ? new Date(event.target.value) : null;
    this.emitDateRangeIfComplete();
  }

  // Emits only when both start and end date are chosen
  private emitDateRangeIfComplete(): void {
    if (this.startDate && this.endDate) {
      this.dateRangeSelected.emit({
        startDate: this.startDate,
        endDate: this.endDate,
      });
      console.log('-- Emit function runs');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.startDateInput.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', (e: Event) => {
      const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
      console.log('Start date is: ' + input.value);
    });

    this.endDateInput.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', (e: Event) => {
      const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
      console.log('End date is: ' + input.value);
    });
  }
}

HTML:
<div id="date-range-picker" date-rangepicker>
  <div class="relative">
    <div
      class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none"
    >
      <i class="ci-Calendar_Days text-lg"></i>
    </div>
    <input
      #datepickerRangeStart
      id="datepicker-range-start"
      name="start"
      [(ngModel)]="startDate"
      (change)="onStartDateChange($event)"
      class="bg-gray-50 border text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg block ps-10 p-2.5 cursor-pointer"
      placeholder="{{ 'Select start date' | translate }}"
      autocomplete="off"
      readonly
    />
  </div>
  <span class="mx-2 text-gray-500">{{ "to" | translate }}</span>
  <div class="relative">
    <div
      class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none"
    >
      <i class="ci-Calendar_Days text-lg"></i>
    </div>
    <input
      #datepickerRangeEnd
      id="datepicker-range-end"
      name="end"
      [(ngModel)]="endDate"
      (change)="onEndDateChange($event)"
      class="bg-gray-50 border text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg block ps-10 p-2.5 cursor-pointer"
      placeholder="{{ 'Select end date' | translate }}"
      autocomplete="off"
      readonly
    />
  </div>
</div>


From this GitHub comment, use changeDate event listener/binding instead of change.
<input
    #datepickerRangeStart
    id="datepicker-range-start"
    name="start"
    [(ngModel)]="startDate"
    (changeDate)="onStartDateChange($event)"
    class="bg-gray-50 border text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg block ps-10 p-2.5 cursor-pointer"
    placeholder="{{ 'Select start date' }}"
    autocomplete="off"
    readonly
  />

<input
    #datepickerRangeEnd
    id="datepicker-range-end"
    name="end"
    [(ngModel)]="endDate"
    (changeDate)="onEndDateChange($event)"
    class="bg-gray-50 border text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg block ps-10 p-2.5 cursor-pointer"
    placeholder="{{ 'Select end date' }}"
    autocomplete="off"
    readonly
  />

Demo @ StackBlitz

Instead of flowbite which does not cater to angular two way bindings and other features, you should consider flowbite-angular
I am aware that it does not have a datepicker yet available, but it will be present in the future.

Would recommend you choose a more mature UI library until flowbite-angular is good to go for angular. Currently it's two early and will just give you headaches, writing plain javascript for listeners using flowbite (as seen in the question), this eliminates the advantages and power that angular brings to the table.

At the time of answering this question, flowbite-angular is early stage, but in future it should be readily available for use.
